# Performance of SortedDictionary vs sorting a Dictionary

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, time-complexity, sorteddictionary

I have a list of objects. These objects have many properties including price and quantity. I need to create a new dictionary with key 'price' and value 'quantity'. If two objects have the same price, then the resulting dictionary should have the price as key and the sum of the quantities of both objects as value. As per my knowledge, I can do this in two ways.

1. Using `Dictionary` data structure, and sort the final dictionary:

```
var result = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach(List<object> obj in list) {
    if(result.ContainsKey(obj.price)) {
        result[price] += quantity;
    }
    else {
        result[price] = quantity;
    }
}
result = result.OrderBy(x => x.Key);
```

2. Using `SortedDictionary`:

```
var result = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
foreach(List<object> obj in list) {
    if(result.ContainsKey(obj.price)) {
        result[price] += quantity;
    }
    else {
        result[price] = quantity;
    }
}
```

In the first method, the time complexity for `ContainsKey` is `O(1)` and for sorting, order by uses quicksort which has time complexity `O(nlogn)`. So the total time complexity would be `O(nlogn)`. In the second method, the `ContainsKey` of sortedDictionary already takes `O(log n)` and as I am repeating this for `n` times, the total complexity would be `O(nlogn)`. As per my calculation, I feel using both methods should take the same time. Please correct me if I'm wrong. And, if I'm wrong, which method has better performance?

Comment: If sorting by inserting in sorted dictionary would be faster than just sorting, would not be sorting implemented via sorted dictionary? Also same time complexity in terms of Big-O notation does not mean that runtime would be the same.

Comment: Also have you tried to measure time spent using both approaches on your data?

Comment: @GuruStron I didn't measure the time taken for both approaches. And, the time complexity might not mean the runtime is the same but it is a healthy way to code based on time complexity, right? And, by the first half of your first message, do you suggest method 1 is efficient?

Comment: You can't order a dictionary using `OrderBy()` because that returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, so your sample code won't compile - therefore the two approaches are NOT the same.

Comment: @user147504 it is healthy, but still it should not be the only  thing to cosider. And in the end you should always test based on the estimated amount of data to process and actual data itself.

Comment: Can you please explain how the result will be used? In your "need" part of statement there is nothing about need of sorting, for example. What is actual task?

Comment: @GuruStron I don't have a large data set to test this. I never used SortedDictionary. So I'm trying to explore it by practicing some online challenge and I got a doubt about how it would work in this kind of situation. The next thing I need to do is to iterate through the result dictionary

Comment: So you don't actually need a dictionary in the result? Can you post the actual challenge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 will usually be faster. It is easier to sort once than to maintain a sorted dictionary.

Big-O complexity might be the same, but equal complexity does not mean equal performance.

**Benchmark results:**

```
|      Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |  Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|------------ |---------:|---------:|---------:|-------:|------:|------:|----------:|
|        Dict | 361.7 ns |  7.07 ns |  7.26 ns | 0.1554 |     - |     - |     488 B |
| DictOrderBy | 499.9 ns |  9.66 ns |  9.04 ns | 0.2651 |     - |     - |     832 B |
|  SortedDict | 943.7 ns | 18.26 ns | 22.42 ns | 0.2241 |     - |     - |     704 B |
```

**Code:** https://gist.github.com/ptupitsyn/71eefbdb607ce3f9ddfae2f5e099184e

**Notes:**

- `TryGetValue` eliminates an extra dictionary lookup
- All benchmark methods return results as `List` in an attempt to make it fair